# Is it permissible to have food that has squid in it, or eat the food but not the squid?

Tags: halal-haram, food

I am staying in Korea for my study and in my University they prepare a dish of noodles where they give prawn and squid. They put water, noodles, prawn and squid there and cook it. So far I know squid is not permitted. Can I eat that food except the squid? Or as it is cooked together I can not have that?

Comment: Please provide your reference that squid is not halal. Are you seeking an answer from a Sunni or a Shia view?

Comment: According to the following link it is said Squid is not halal for Hanafi Followers.

Comment: http://www.questionsonislam.com/question/it-haram-forbidden-eat-squid-calamari

Comment: I am seeking an answer from Sunni view.

Comment: According to the article squid in not halal for Hanafi (which I follow). My question is if I can have the other parts of that dish like prawn and noodles but not the squid? Or the whole dish will be haram for me as they are cooked together? I am here for studying and will be here for two years.